# IBM MobileFirst Platform: Is the set Friendly name added in native sdks

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is the SetFriendlyName method added to the latest build of IBM MobileFirst Platform SDK 7.1 version in the native libraries(Native Android/IOS) of the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the API reference for [Android](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLClient.html#getFriendlyName(com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLResponseListener)) and [iOS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/Classes/WLClient.html#//api/name/setFriendlyName:withCompletionHandler:)

Comment: Hi Srik, Thanks for replying. I know this was added in December release. But it was removed due to some issue in analytics. My question was that fixed and brought it back .